# Inserting Magento widget inserts image of widget and not the widget itself

Tags: magento-1.7, widgets

I'm trying to add extension widget to CMS page, but for some reason it just inserts image of Magento widget to CMS page content. If I hide editor code shows:

```
<p><img src="http://mydomain.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/widget/default.gif" /></p>
```

[image]

So on actual page where widget should be displayed I can only see Magento widget icon. It doesn't matter what widget I try to insert, result is always same. I have many extensions, but none of them has anything to do with widgets.

Comment: Maybe you could show us your code, if the extension is your own. Or give us a link to the extension in magento connect.